# Let $T : \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2 $ such that $T^2 = T \circ T = 0$. Show that: a)$Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$...

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, similar-matrices

Let $T : \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2 $ such that $T^2 = T \circ T = 0$. Show that:

a)$Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$;

b)If $T \ne 0$, then there is a basis $\cal{B}$ over $\mathbb C^2$ that $[T]_{\cal{B}} = $ $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
      \end{pmatrix}$

c)Conclude that given $N \in \mathbb M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb C)$ a non-zero matrix with entries in $\mathbb C$ such that $N^2 = 0, N$ is similar ( still over $\mathbb C$) to matrix $B = \begin{pmatrix}  0& 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

---

Hello, I'm very lost in this exercise (probably in the subject too) but I managed to at least get an idea of how to solve item a) and item c) I don't know if they are correct, but that's what I managed to do. b) I couldn't even get started. Here's my attempt:

a) Let any $v \in V, T^2(v)=T(T(v)) = 0$, so $T(v) \in ker(T)$ for any $v$ then {$T(v):v \in V$}$=T(V) \subset ker(T)$. Now suppose, $T(V) \subset ker(T)$. For any $v \in V$, $T^2(v)=T(T(v))=0$, so $T^2$ is the zero.

c) $2 \times 2$ matrices are similar if and only if they have the same characteristic polynomial, and neither of them is multiple of the identity.

$B$ characteristic polynomial is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
      \end{pmatrix} - \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
      \end{pmatrix} \to det \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & 0 \\
1 & -\lambda \\
      \end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2$

$N$ characteristic polynomial is

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
      \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\ \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + bc & ab + bd \\
ac + dc & cb + d^2 \\
      \end{pmatrix}$ $= 0 \to \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-\frac{a^2}{b}& -a \\
      \end{pmatrix} $

$ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-\frac{a^2}{b}& -a \\
      \end{pmatrix} - \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
      \end{pmatrix} \to det \begin{pmatrix}
a-\lambda & b \\
-\frac{a^2}{b} & -a -\lambda \\
      \end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2$

So they are similar.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Two $2 \times 2$ matrices are similar if and only if either they have the same characteristic polynomial, and neither of them is a scalar multiple of the identity, **or** they are the same scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: Part (c) is meant to be deduced from (a) and (b) : it is immediate once you realise that if you move to a new basis then the matrix moves to a similar matrix.